# Как получить текст из квадратных скобок?

Tags: php

Есть строка вида:

```
TestPage[index]
```

Мне нужно получить только слово **index** , то есть то которое в квадратных скобках.

В строке квадратные скобки всегда только одни.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Используем метод `substr(string $string, int $offset, ?int $length = null): string` для получения подстроки строки, который *возвращает подстроку строки string, начинающейся с offset символа по счету и длиной length символов*.

```
$str = "TestPage[index]";
$offset = strpos($str, "["); // возвращает index "["
$length = strpos($str, "]")-strpos($str, "["); //для нахождения длины строки вычтем из индекса "]" индекс "[", которые найдём при помощи strpos
$result = substr($str,$offset+1, $length-1); // +1 и -1, так как нам не нужно включать "[" и "]"
echo $result; // index
```

Можно записать сразу так:

```
$str = "TestPage[index]";
echo substr($str,strpos($str, "[")+1, strpos($str, "]")-strpos($str, "[")-1); //index
```

Решение через `preg_match` с использованием регулярного выражения:

```
$str = "TestPage[index]";
$output_array = array();
preg_match('/(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/', $str, $output_array);
echo $output_array[0]; // index
```

Comment: А preg_match не лучше будет?

Comment: Хороший вопрос насчёт "лучше". Лучше по каким критериям? Мне решение через `substr` нравится больше, поскольку `preg_match` возвращает массив, а не строку. Но с другой стороны, решение с использованием регулярного выражения смотрится лаконичней. В любом случае, добавил его в ответ.

Comment: проще маска `\[(.+?)\]`

Comment: echo preg_replace(array("/.*\[/", "/\].*/"), "", $str);